# replace xml value with sed

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I would like to replace value in XML file. Sample XML

```
<Console>
                <!-- REQUIRED PARAMETERS -->
                <!-- Enter the node that you are running the installation program from. This value must be a fully qualified name, which includes a host name and domain name. For example, node001.server.name.com.-->
                <node>node.sample.ibm.com</node>

                <!-- Enter the domain name of the cluster as a single dot-separated string. For example, server.name.com. -->
        <sso-domain-name>sample.ibm.com</sso-domain-name>

        <!-- Set this property to true if your InfoSphere BigInsights Console uses HTTPS. Otherwise, enter false. -->
                <https>false</https>

        <!-- management-console-port specifies which port is used by the Management Console. -->
        <management-console-port>8080</management-console-port>
```

I would like to replace  value.
I tried with following but its not working. Any help appreciated.

```
sed -i "/<Console>/,/<\/Console>/ s/<node>[0-9][a-z]\+/<node>newvalue
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question. But you could also use 'xmllint' on the command line. This handles with the XML structure directly.

Comment: Don't [summon Cthulhu](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).

Comment: @Wintermute for simple XML [xml2](http://www.ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/) works very well

Comment: this is not a duplicate because Q asks for `sed` precisely

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
sed -i -e '/<Console>/,/<\/Console>/ s|<node>[0-9a-z.]\{1,\}</node>|<node>newvalue</node>|g' YourFile
```

i assume value is between your tag  and  and only contain small letter, dot and digit (based on your sample and try). If extended, just add character missing in the class like `[0-9a-z._-A-Z:]` and maybe sub-class [:space:]

if `newvalue` is a variable content, dont forget to use double quote and escape character `&`, `\` and the separator of sed `s` action (default is `/` and `|` in my code)

Comment: Thanks NeronLeVelu , it worked

Comment: Yes newvalue is a variable, how would it be in that case ?

Comment: if NewValue does not contain & \, just replace the surrounding simple quote by double quote on sed action. If it contain those char, escape them before using it in the string and use double quote

Comment: Thanks a lot  NeronLeVelu. It worked.

Answer (score 8):

You could use xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u //Console/node -v 'new value'
```

(Or something similar)

Answer (score 1):

Simple XML can be handled with the [xml2](http://www.ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/) suite quite well.

You can translate an XML into a line-based format and work on that like you are used to. i.e.:

```
xml2 < x.xml | perl -pe 's|^(/Console/node=)(.*)$|$1newvalue|g' | 2xml > y.xml
```

I am not so versed in *sed* I am sure you can replace *perl* with *sed* easily.

Comment: Very interesting. But I'd prefer a perl-less solution ;-)

Comment: @choroba good point. but I am even less able with sed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper XML parser. E.g., here is what I would do in [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
open 1.xml ;
for //Console/node {
    if xsh:matches(., '[0-9][a-z]+') set text() 'newvalue' ;
}
save :b ;
```

Comment: very interesting. But I would prefer a perl-less solution.