# Replacing a value in a XML file for a particular tag

Tags: xml, linux, sed

I have a XML file, MyFile.xml on my Linux machine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project>
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
          <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
          <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
              <env name="envvar" value="/opt/environment/environment.properties" />
              <env name="JDBC_Driver"  value="/opt/JDBC/ojdb6.jar" />
              <env name="agent/enable" value="true" />
</project>
```

I need to change the value to `"false"` (when it is true) and `"true"` (when it is false) for the `env name="agent/enable"` tag in the XML file whenever I get a requirement.

I just wanted to use some shell script for this. I know this can be done using Sed command in Linux, but I'm not good at regular expressions. So that whenever I get a requirement to change I can just run a script.

Note: script should change the XML file and should be saved on the file system with same name.

Comment: In general, we encourage people to give problems such as this a go, and we try to discourage "do it for me" questions - primarily because it may not help the OP learn anything. If you can edit even the start of this into your question, it really helps both you and us.

Comment: Apologies for that halfer!!! Cheers :)

Comment: (Sorry, I have rolled back your edit. We tend to edit questions to be as succinct as possible here, remove excessive formatting, use inline code formatting rather than bold, and trim requests for urgent help).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace dynamic content in XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369933/replace-dynamic-content-in-xml-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not attempt to edit XML with plain-text tools; it can only end badly. Nobody expects their XML tools to break when they insert a newline into the XML or change a `<foo/>` node to `<foo></foo>`, but they will if they're based on sed (and not ridiculously complex).

Instead, use a proper XML-parsing tool such as `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u '/project/env[@name="agent/enable"]/@value' -x 'string(not(. = "true"))' filename.xml
```

#### Explanation

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u <foo> -x <bar> filename.xml
```

updates nodes that fit the XPath expression `<foo>` to have the value of the XPath expression `<bar>`,

```
/project/env[@name="agent/enable"]/@value
```

is an XPath expression that selects the `value` attribute of `env` nodes whose `name` attribute is `agent/enable` and that are a child of the `project` root node -- this should describe the value you want to change adequately -- and

```
string(not(. = "true"))
```

is an XPath expression that is `false` if the currently inspected value is `"true"` and `true` otherwise. The currently inspected value is the old value of the `value` attribute that's being updated.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```
sed -i '/<env\s\+name="agent\/enable"/s/value="true"/value="false"/' f.xml
```