# how can I change the value in xml using bash

Tags: xml, bash

how can I change the value in xml using bash

`<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Keep Accounts</string>
    <string name="login">"login"</string>
    <string name="login_password">"password："</string>
    <string name="login_account_hint">input to login</string>
    <string name="login_password_hint">input your password</string>
    <string name="login_fail">login failed</string>
</resources>`

For example I want to change the value "Keep Accounts" to "Keep Accounts 2".The "app_name" may not only be "Keep Accounts",but also other values,let's say XXX,but the "app_name" is certain,I want the output be:

`<resources>
    <string name="app_name">XXX 2</string>
    <string name="login">"login"</string>
    <string name="login_password">"password："</string>
    <string name="login_account_hint">input to login</string>
    <string name="login_password_hint">input your password</string>
    <string name="login_fail">login failed</string>
</resources>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace dynamic content in XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369933/replace-dynamic-content-in-xml-file)

Comment: I suspect that you need to show us a bit more context; at the moment your problem can be solved by `sed 's/Keep Accounts/& 2/' file.xml` but it's the wrong tool for the job and probably won't work with your real data.

Comment: the items may be so many,so it should be select by "app_name",then change the value.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a more complete example along with the desired output.

Comment: I update the question : )  Hope it can be understood

Answer (score 1):

Use a XML aware tool. I'd do it in [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh):

```
open file.xml ;
insert text " 2" into /resources/string ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: Looks like a nice tool!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/<string name=\"app_name\">.*<\/string>/<string name=\"app_name\">NewName<\/string>/g' xml_filename.xml
```

The single line  sed  (bash) solution to replace any 'app_name'

Use sed -i to replace the contents of the file in question

I assumed you have the xml content in a file named xml_filename.xml but change this as required

Comment: -i.bu is Ok. But I want the new name based on the old name. For example the old name is "Hello",the new name should be "Hello(new)"

Answer (score 0):

if you have python-pip installed, you can install xq with pip install yq, then try this(I have tested it works):

```
xmldoc=$(cat <<'EOF'
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Keep Accounts</string>
    <string name="login">"login"</string>
    <string name="login_password">"password："</string>
    <string name="login_account_hint">input to login</string>
    <string name="login_password_hint">input your password</string>
    <string name="login_fail">login failed</string>
</resources>
EOF
)
echo "$xmldoc" | xq '.resources.string = ([.resources.string[]|select(."#text" == "Keep Accounts") ."#text" = "Keep Accounts 2"])' -x
```